# When/why/how do unqualified names look in dependent base?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

For up to C++17 I find this wording in [temp.dep]p3

> In the definition of a class or class template, the scope of a dependent base class (17.7.2.1) is not examined
> during unqualified name lookup either at the point of definition of the class template or member or during
> an instantiation of the class template or member.

But looking at the newest draft (on eel.is), it appears this changed. This text does not appear at the place anymore, and I don't know whether this rule is still in place, or in weaker form (maybe they are looked up if they are dependent, but illformed if a base-class member is found?) or not at all!

Comment: "*But looking at the newest draft (on eel.is),*" Note that said draft incorporates post-C++20 changes and may not be accurate to what C++20 is. [This particular draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/) more accurately reflects the contents of C++20 and has no post-20 changes.

Comment: It also contains the statement in question. So you definitely are talking about post-C++20 changes.

Comment: @Nicol thanks! In that version, the paragraph is still there (as p4). Unfortunately a quick skim over the cwg defects and issues list did not give any insight into what might have caused the deletion! Maybe the paragraph "dissolved" into text elsewhere.

Comment: I know that post-C++20 has done a lot with consolidating scoping rules. Where they moved to, I can't say.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing has changed.  The relevant rule is [now](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html) [class.member.lookup]/4:

> Calculate the lookup set for *N* in each direct non-dependent ([temp.dep.type]) base class […]

so that there need not be a special override for the name-lookup rules in [temp].

Comment: Thanks for the authorative answer. I wasn't aware things were cleaned up that much! However I found the note " If T is an instantiated class, its base classes are not dependent.". I'm totally inexperienced with the new rules, but does that not mean that a name like "auto x = &operator T;" in the instantiated class might find a member declaration from a class template specialization instantiated from a dependent base class?

Comment: Ah, screw that! It must be qualified if the address is taken... And if I call it like 'operator T()', the dependent call rules kick in and only enable ADL in the instantiation context. Thanks again!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Indeed, making `operator T` a dependent name (even if unqualified) was another fix in the same paper to make sure that such lookup could work.

Comment: I'm glad that DR#554 finally was fixed. It only took 15 years!

Comment: Hope it also fixes the issue I reported in c++std-core-18532! Unfortunately it appeared to have been lost and no entry was created in cwg-active :(

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: It looks like the rephrasing makes it clear _which_ branch of your message is a problem--it's the "which derived class is it?" one--but that's all.

Comment: I just looked at your paper R5, and what has always confused me is the inconsistent use of "same" for names. On the one side "Two names are the same if 1. they are identifier⁠s composed of the same character sequence" (lexical) but on the other side "Two declarations correspond if they (re)introduce the same name" (here a "name" has kind-of an identity). Should the latter not say "same name in the same target scope"?

Comment: I just went through my mails and found this case that got no reply: `template<typename T>
struct A {
  operator int() { return 0; }

  void f() {
    operator T();
  }
};

int main() {
  A<int> a;
  a.f();
}`. Would your fix also fix this case? GCC at the time (27.4.2012) rejected this code (because in the instantiation context, only ADL is done). But clang accepted it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: First, there was an R6, but that’s not important here: “same” *is* consistent there, because it’s comparing the names written in the two declarations (which can in fact be in different scopes: that’s checked along *with* “corresponds” as needed).  Yes, your `a.f()` should work now.

Comment: I see now, nice!

Comment: digging a bit deeper, I found that "[basic.link]" widely still thinks of a name as being a "name, target scope" pair. For example it attributes linkage to names! So, does "n" have internal or external linkage? "int n; namespace m { static int n; }". If you have to ask "which n?", both n are _not_ the same name, contradicting [basic]p9.

Comment: But maybe I have the wrong concept of "same name". Comparing with values in a stable search, one can still distinguish multiple values that are "the same", with regard to the sorting, but may have different properties beyond that, if only it's their relative position. (But for the sorting scenario, it's obvious that the items are still distinct items. With the definition of names, I don't find that this is obvious).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: As you’ve discovered, [basic.link] **also** needs rewriting.  C++20 does drop the outdated notion of *types* having linkage separate from their names, so in the future it will be possible to rephrase linkage as pertaining to entities rather than their names.